# How do I create logs from within a module?

Tags: python, logging

I have two files- one is my script and another is a module I'm using.

In the module, I have this function-

```
def sumTwoInts(x, y):
   logger.debug('Lets sum two ints')
   return x + y
```

In my script, I want to instantiate the log file

```
import logging
import myModule

logging.basicConfig(filename = 'logs.log')
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

myModule.sumTwoInts(1, 3)
```

How do I get the logger.debug code to add to the logs.log file created in my script?

Comment: What exactly is not working with the way you have it now?

Comment: These are in two different files, so the logger. command doesn't work

Comment: Specifically, the module doesn't have the logger config, so it doesn't know where to send the message. I'm thinking maybe I have to pass the 'logger' object

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you add

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

and then run your main program, then `logs.log` will contain

```
DEBUG:myModule:Lets sum two ints
```

Isn't that what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is already working if the `logger` is defined in the module file.

Note that I removed the `file` option from the `basicConfig` to check the result on the console.  If you set it back, the log result will be added to the file.

```py
# myModule.py
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def sumTwoInts(x, y):
   logger.debug('Lets sum two ints')
   return x + y
```

```py
# main.py
import logging
import myModule

logging.basicConfig()
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

myModule.sumTwoInts(1, 3)
```

```sh
python main.py
# DEBUG:myModule:Lets sum two ints
```